# AWS get bandwidth / space used per bucket

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, amazon-cloudwatch

How can i get the total bandwidth used by one of my aws s3 bucket using cloudwatch `CLI` . Name of my bucket -  `'helloworld'`

i've tested oer newRelic and its working fine .

```
http://tech.degica.com/en/2016/02/08/lambda-insights-en/
```

so i need a response something like

total space = 1003388M

total bandwidth = 3488M

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Amazon CloudWatch** can provide the following [metrics for Amazon S3](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/cloudwatch-monitoring.html):

- Storage space
- Number of objects

[**Amazon S3 Bucket Logging**](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/UG/ManagingBucketLogging.html) provide details about the S3 requests, such as the request type, the resources specified in the request worked, and the time and date the request was processed. I'm not sure how fast these logs are delivered.

**Bandwidth** consumed by Amazon S3 operations is visible in the monthly [Detailed Billing Report](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/awsaccountbilling/latest/aboutv2/detailed-billing-reports.html), broken-down by bucket.

Comment: So how we will get the traffic used by each bucket . If we need realtime info through API

Comment: There is no realtime information about bandwidth consumed. I've also added a reference to S3 Bucket Logging, which can provide information about files accessed. I'm not sure how close to 'realtime' that is.

Comment: Neat! It apparently downloads the CloudFront logs and the S3 Bucket logs, does the analysis, then uploads the results. I'm not sure how often it runs, so it probably isn't 'realtime'.